# Source for a Chatat offering on behalf of deceased father and alive son

Tags: sin, korban

I think this is a gemara, but I'm not sure where. I heard that you can still bring a chatat that had been separated already on behalf of a father and son who both did the same sin, but then the father dies and the son is still allowed to bring the Korban.

Comment: Nazir 4:7?  It includes a chatat but not for a sin

Comment: Keritot 6:7 is relevant

Answer (score 2):

The Gemarah in [Temurah (16a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Temurah.16a) brings from R'Shimon a Halacha L'moshe Mi-Sinai that there are 5 types of Korbon Chatos that are left to die, and not brought up on the mizbeach. One of the 5 is a Chatos that the owner has died.

The Gemorah in [Zevachim (5a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.5a) brings down a case of a lady who is required to bring a korban Olah and a korban Chatos (she is required to bring these because she gave birth) and she then died. The Gemorah writes that her inheritors can bring her korban Olah, but not her Korban Chatos.

Comment: thanks! I guess I misheard. Is there any scenario except the korbanot hatzibur, Kohel gadol, or beit din, when a Chatat can be brought by 2 or more people?